# how to fix stretching image in image view in android when i use fitxy Scale type in android

Tags: android

```
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/bigimages"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="150dp"
android:layout_below="@+id/productTitle"
android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
android:scaleType="fitXY"
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
android:src="@drawable/bath_and_body_1" />



 Glide.with(this)
                .load("https://images-eu.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41ZNY84Q-7L.jpg")
                .placeholder(R.drawable.cancel_icon)
                .into(bigimages);
```

https://images-eu.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41ZNY84Q-7L.jpg

this is my code and image URl i have to display full image without streching but i am not able to display its stretched please suggest me how to fix it .  below is current image which is stretched

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ufHX.png)

how to fix there is stretching in text yellow....

Answer (score 0):

YOu can try :

```
android:scaleType="fitXY"
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```

Comment: i tried with this @Thientvse  not working still image Streched

Answer (score 0):

Change to

```
android:scaleType="centerCrop"
```

or

```
Glide.with(this)
            .load("https://images-eu.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41ZNY84Q-7L.jpg")
            .placeholder(R.drawable.cancel_icon)
            .centerCrop()
            .into(bigimages);
```

Comment: i tried with centerCrop but still its not working @KeLiuyue plz help me

Answer (score 0):

Of the various `scaleType` options, `fitXY` is specifically made to stretch the image. It will make sure that the entire image is stretched/shrunk to fit in exactly the space provided.

You probably want `centerInside`; this will make sure that the entire image fits within the view, and will not distort the aspect ratio. If your view is square and the image is rectangular, `centerInside` will scale the image down so that it fits inside the view, meaning either the top+bottom or left+right will be empty.

Comment: even i tried with centerInside also its not working @Ben P.

Answer (score 0):

Alter your `Glide` implementation with:

```
Glide.with(this)
         .load("https://images-eu.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41ZNY84Q-7L.jpg")
         .override(width, height) //set width & height as you want
         .palceholder(R.drawable.cancel_icon)
         .into(bigimages);
```

References:

1. [Glide Image Resizing & Scaling](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/glide-image-resizing-scaling)
2. [Glide Documentation](http://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/targets.html#view-targets)

Comment: its not working can u please tell me how to adjust image in given size of imageview